# Cross-compile dbus for mips

Tags: mips, dbus

I am trying to cross-compile dbus for mips, which will be used for alljoyn framework.

~ alljoyn dep on dbus

~ dbus dep on glib

~ glib dep on ffi and python

This is where I am running into dependency issues. Initially had dep with `libffi`, which after cross compile and setting `LIBFFI_CFLAGS`, `LIBFFI_LIBS` has been resolved. Python is being taken from the system. Now the configure fails in not finding `gettext`.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
checking for msgfmt... no
configure: error:
*** You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
*** GNU gettext library. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have again cross-compiled gettext, installed in a prefix dir [as of others], pointed the `LDPATH` to the libs, but still am getting this error.
Just a note, after cross-compile of `gettext` it did not create a `pkgconfig` file although the build was successful.